# Python global threading.condition() and use in multiple modules

Tags: python, multithreading, module

**EDIT: the problem I was experiencing was not related to the structure of my program.  It was FAPWS3's routing picking a similar, closely named function.**

I have a large program spread across multiple files.  I need to use the threading.condition() locking functionality across these files.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.  In production I do not get any errors, but the state of the lock does not seem to be shared (I can acquire in one thread, and acquire in another thread without the previous being released).

main.py

```
import servera, serverb

# some code that deploys server-a and server-b as threads
```

constants.py

```
import threading
mylock = threading.Condition()
```

servera.py

```
from constants import mylock

Class ServerA():
  def doSomething():
    mylock.acquire()
    # do something
    mylock.release()
```

serverb.py

```
from constants import mylock

Class ServerB():
  def doSomethingElse():
    mylock.acquire()
    # do something else
    mylock.release()
```

Comment: Your comments don't really explain why you might be having an issue;  Please post a minimal example of working code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correct, when you import an module Python runs it. So I think you get a different mylock in each file.
You could try printing it and look at the ids.

Jeffs link posted below clears that:

> Because there is only one instance of each module, any changes made to the module object get reflected everywhere.

So this is not a problem.

Comment: That's what I figured, how would I reference a global mylock then?

Comment: Actually, according to http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules.htm I think I am sharing the variable correctly.